# Cakephp - Pagination with JSON API

Tags: cakephp, backbone.js

I am developing (with a partner) a CakePHP application which will use Backbone.js.

So, basically, my cake application largely behaves like a JSON API. After the controller action loads a certain view (no data is rendered yet), Backbone makes an AJAX call to another controller action to fetch the data. The controller return JSON.

(The routes.php file has the mapResources and parseExtensions line in place)

Controller code

```
public function index(){            
    $company_id = $this->Session->read('Company.id');
    $channel_ids = $this->Order->Channel->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Channel.company_id' => $company_id), 'fields' => array('Channel.id')));
    $channel_ids = Set::extract('/Channel/id', $channel_ids);        

    $data = $this->paginate('Order', array('Order.fulfillment_status_id' => 1, 'Order.channel_id' => $channel_ids));
    $this->set('orders', $data);
    //In case of a JSON request
    if($this->RequestHandler->ext == 'json') {           
        $this->autoRender = false;
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
```

This worked fine, but we hit a wall when we tried to implement pagination with this.

1. How do we generate the Pagination links? (If we do it via Backbone, it does not know the total records in the database and hence does not know how many links to generate)
2. How should the "page number" be burnt into the AJAX call? How should it be deciphered in the controller?

Really stuck here, we will really appreciate your help.

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html#ajax-pagination

Answer (score 3):

In Your Controller

```
$this->layout = false;
$this->RequestHandler->respondAs('json'); 
$recipes = $this->paginate('Recipe');
$this->set(compact('recipes'));
```

In your View

```
echo json_encode($recipes);
echo json_encode($this->Paginator->params());
```